# Populating a Junction Table

Tags: sqlite, bulk-insert

I'm a SQLite and SQL beginner so please bear with me. I'm trying my hand a creating a simple podcast index database. Here's the schema for my `EPISODE`, `CAST_MEMBER`, and `EPISODE_CAST` tables.

```
CREATE TABLE EPISODE
(
    id                  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    show_number         INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    air_date            DATE UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    runtime             VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CAST_MEMBER
(
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    person_name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE EPISODE_CAST
(
    episode_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cast_member_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(episode_id, cast_member_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(episode_id) REFERENCES EPISODE(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(cast_member_id) REFERENCES CAST_MEMBER(id)
);
```

I'm trying to find a quick way to populate the EPISODE_CAST table. I know what all the relationships should be, I just don't want to have to write a million insert statements. For example, one cast member has been on every episode of the show so I naturally want 550 rows added to the table

```
episode_id | cast_member_id
===========================
1          | 1
2          | 1
3          | 1
```

… and so on.

So here's the query that I've written

```
INSERT INTO EPISODE_CAST (episode_id, cast_member_id) VALUES
   ((SELECT id FROM EPISODE WHERE show_number BETWEEN 1 AND 550),
   (SELECT id FROM CAST_MEMBER WHERE person_name='John Smith'));
```

But I'm only ever getting one row inserted. (The 1|1 row.) So I'm obviously missing something here. A loop of some sort…

Once I have that one cast member in there, I'd also like to do something similar with the other cast members. But for them I'll be using an `IN` clause with the set of all the episodes that person was in (most are non-contiguous).

Again, sorry for my naïvety. But thanks for any help.

Comment: You should look at using a JOIN statement. SELECT the rows you want, using a JOIN, and use that as your INSERT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a Cartesian or cross join.  You can test the select clause separately to ensure it selects the desired data before adding it into the insert.

```
INSERT INTO EPISODE_CAST (episode_id, cast_member_id)
SELECT  episode.id AS episode_id,
        cast_member.id AS cast_member_id
FROM EPISODE CROSS JOIN CAST_MEMBER 
WHERE show_number BETWEEN 1 AND 550
AND   person_name='John Smith';
```

Comment: Almost there! I ran the `select` part separately and it grabbed everything I wanted. But when I run the whole `insert` I'm getting a syntax error: "Error near "select": syntax error". Unfortunately, the error isn't any more descriptive than that. Any ideas?

Comment: @MatthewJ It looks like the brackets around the select shouldn't be there.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I got it working with one minor change: removing the word `VALUES` from the statement. If you can edit your answer to do that, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @MatthewJ  Editted.